# Browser extension/plugin to monitor website source code and alert changes

Tags: javascript, html, browser, browser-plugin, browser-extension

Is it possible (and does eventually yet exist) a browser extension or plugin that logs (or hashes) all html and javascript code that is loaded from a website/url.

The use case is that I want to check if all security promises of the website vendor are kept ***all the time*** (i.e. correct hashing of my password). So when I once have checked the complete source code of the site and load the page the next time, the plugin should tell me if there are any changes to the prior version.

I know there are many problems with such a solution (i.e. dynamically loaded code). But perhaps there is someone out there who has thought through or solved such issues yet?

Comment: You cannot do what you want with a plugin (see http://npapi.com/extensions) but you could use a plugin to help with the logging if an extension can do it.

Comment: update 2016 - the html5 webworker (especially service workers) will allow you to just do that. The workers can be included into an extension aswell.

Comment: perhaps load and check the code 'offline' using curl or wget ?